# getting error in mysql backup using mysqldump command

Tags: mysql

I want to take backup for 3308 port in mysql using below given mysqldump command ,but I am getting this error.plz help.

```
mysqldump  -h 172.16.150.10 -P 3308 -uroot -proot rt_CallAnalysis  > b.sql
```

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION
>   SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)

Comment: Hi, Can you please show the query? Expecially the rows near `OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1` because there's a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that MySQL 5.6 has removed support for “SET OPTION” and your mysql client tools are probably on older version.

you just see this [link](http://www.markomedia.com.au/mysqldump-mysql-5-6-problem-solved/) more detail.meet your answer.